# Can we host yum and apt repo from same machine/server?

Tags: ubuntu, repository, redhat, yum, apt

How can we host both yum and apt repository from same server ?

yum in redhat based tool while apt is debian based tool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be help Follow  this link and download yum and apt

http://www.webmo.net/support/yum_repository.html

For more information:

http://agix.com.au/blog/?p=1280

Comment: Thanks for the first link. The first article points to the "Creating a Redhat Apt Repository" page, but the inner link is broken. Here is the copy:
https://web.archive.org/web/20080223002704/https://www.webmo.net/support/apt_repository

Comment: The second link is also broken. Here is the copy: https://web.archive.org/web/20140228173006/https://agix.com.au/blog/?p=1280 . But I fail to see how it's related to the server-side things of hosting both RPM or APT repositories. IMO this only describes the client-side things, has a ton of alternatives and is of little value. Oh, I see that answer is 10y old – maybe there were too few of such articles at the time.